# how to replace all occurences of a string or character, unless already escaped?

Tags: c++, string, boost

Is there a nice and elegant way (using boost::algorithm::replace maybe?) to replace all occurrences of a character in a string - unless preceded by a backslash?

so that

```
std::string s1("hello 'world'");
my_replace(s1, "'", "''"); // s1 becomes "hello ''world''"

std::string s2("hello \\'world'"); // note: only a single backslash in the string
my_replace(s2, "'", "''"); // s2 becomes "hello \\'world''"
```

Using boost::regex, this can be done using:

```
std::string my_replace (std::string s, std::string search, std::string format) {
  boost::regex e("([^\\\\])" + search);
  return boost::regex_replace(s, e, "\\1" + format);
}
```

But I prefer not to use boost::regex due to performance reasons. boost::algorithm::replace looks like a good fit, but I can't figure out exactly how.

Comment: writing an ad-hoc algorithm shouldn't be too difficult, but i'm not sure if you would consider it "nice and elegant" :-)

Comment: No, `boost::algorithm::replace_*` is not a good fit.  It doesn't work like that, unless you want to go over the string twice, but then, I think you'll lose the precious performance you are so concerned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that does the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string replace(char c, string replacement, string s)
{
    string chars = string("\\") + c;

    size_t pos = s.find_first_of(chars);
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        char& ch = s[pos];    
        if (ch == '\\')
        {
            pos = s.find_first_of(chars, pos + 2);
        }
        else if (ch == c)
        {
            s.replace(pos, 1, replacement);
            pos = s.find_first_of(chars, pos + replacement.length());
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << replace('\'', "''", "hello \\'world'");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Following @BenVoigt's suggestion, I reformulated the algorithm to avoid in-place operations. That should bring further performance improvement:

```
string replace(char c, string replacement, string const& s)
{
    string result;
    size_t searchStartPos = 0;

    string chars = string("\\") + c;
    size_t pos = s.find_first_of(chars);
    while (pos != string::npos)
    {
        result += s.substr(searchStartPos, pos - searchStartPos);
        if (s[pos] == '\\')
        {
            result += string("\\") + c;
            searchStartPos = pos + 2;
        }
        else if (s[pos] == c)
        {
            result += replacement;
            searchStartPos = pos + 1;
        }

        pos = s.find_first_of(chars, searchStartPos);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's nice and clean, although basically I wanted to avoid hand coding the algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: @yhager: I had that feeling yes, but could not find any function that does that in Boost or in the Standard Library, so I thought I would just hand code it

Comment: Thanks. I still have some hope I could conjure something up with boost. If I can't find anything better I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @yhager: Okay. If you find something, please post it as an additional answer and accept it, I'm also curious.

Comment: I've found that boost::algorithm::replace_all is much slower than this even for a simple case, without caring for the backslash. Therefore I've lost interest in finding a boost solution for this, and I'll go with your algorithm. Thx.

Comment: @yhager: I'm glad it helped. I just edited the answer to add a small optimization: instead of calling `erase()` and then `insert()` inside the loop, it is much better to call `replace()`. Simpler code and better efficiency.

Comment: Note: `++pos` followed immediately by `pos = .... pos+1` could be replaced by `pos+2`.  Also, this is pretty inefficient, copying to a string separate from the one being scanned should be much faster than in-place insertion (because repeatedly moving all characters after the insertion point is quite slow).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I changed it into `pos+2`, thank you for that. Also agree on the copying thing, this was just meant to be a simple working example.